# Firebase cloud messaging in an expo managed workflow project without the use of expo push notifications

Tags: react-native, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can you use firebase cloud messaging in an expo managed workflow project without the use of the reliable but limited expo push notifacation library?

The firebase documentation says that i should congigure the app manifest file, but there is no such file in managed workflow. Is it possible to use the expo prebuild command to access those files?